# How to add a post parameter to manual form submission?

Tags: jquery, parameters, http-post, form-submit

I want to submit a form manually after some complicated checks. Because checks involve user interaction, the whole check process is not done synchronously. Here is the scenario:

1. User clicks a button (an HTML `<button id='button-id'>` tag)
2. I prevent the default action of the button (which is the form submission)
3. I do a complicated check.
4. Somewhere in the check process, I show a dialog and wait for the user to respond (here, the original check function proceeds and returns)
5. I provide a callback function for that dialog, which fires and runs when the user closes it (either positive or negative result)
6. Now, I should submit the form, but the original HTML `<button id='button-id'>` should be posted as a [successful control](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2). In other words, I should add the `name` of the button tag as one of the posted parameters to the server.

I use jQuery's `$('#form-id').submit()` method. How can I add the `name` of the `<button>` element to the HTTP Post parameters?

Comment: Instead of directly calling `$('#form-id').submit()`, you could set a flag, whether the validation is over or not and call `$('#button-id').click()` which then triggers `$('#form-id').submit()` instead of the validation. Not sure if this works, but you could give it a try.

Comment: Yeah @FelixKling, that was our first solution. Thanks for suggesting. But that's only a hack. We want to know if we can add something to post parameters or not. This seems to be the straightforward solution. :)

Comment: You could also insert a hidden field into the form with the same name as the `<button>` (and remove or change the button's `name` attribute, of course), and then call `$.submit()`.

Answer (score 4):

You could append a hidden field to your form before submitting -

```
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'buttonid',
    name: 'buttonid',
    value: yourbuttonidvar  
}).appendTo('#form-id');
```

Comment: @ipr101, This isn't answer of this question. but This is a good solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a button type, why not use

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" id="button_id" ...>
```

Comment: you didn't get what I meant. The control itself doesn't matter. What matters is that I cancel it's original behavior. But at last, I want to include it as a successful control in the HTTP Post.

Comment: perhaps not, but - A control's "control name" is given by its name attribute. I thought the problem you were trying to get around is that with a button, the name is not submitted, with an input-submit, it is