# How to add a parameter to a form submission?

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

First, I have to say that I find a similiar question: [How to add a post parameter to manual form submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751650/how-to-add-a-post-parameter-to-manual-form-submission).

But I think that someone can tell me a better solution.

I want to add a name parameter to a form when the user clicks the submit button, this is how I do it:

```
var htmlElement = '<input type="hidden" name="current_step" value="' + $('select#current-step').val() + '"/>';
elForm.append(htmlElement);
```

But I'm not completed satisfied whith this aproach.

Thx in advance if you give me a better way to do it.

Comment: Why don't you just put the `select` inside the form?  Then you don't have to do any javascript handling at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type='hidden' name='current_step' value='' />
<script>
$('#current-step').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name=current_step]').attr('value', $(this).val());
});
</script>
```